# How can I have a row-wise rank in a pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I have a dataset for which I am going to find the rank per row. This is a toy example in `pandas`.

```python
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":[1,2,3,4], "a":[2,7,9,10], 
                   "b":[6,7,4,2], "c":[3,4,8,5]})
print(df)

#    ID   a  b  c
# 0   1   2  6  3
# 1   2   7  7  4
# 2   3   9  4  8
# 3   4  10  2  5

df[["a","b","c"]] = df[["a","b","c"]].rank(method="min", 
                                           ascending=False, 
                                           axis=1).astype("int")
print(df)

#    ID  a  b  c
# 0   1  3  1  2
# 1   2  1  1  3
# 2   3  1  3  2
# 3   4  1  3  2
```

However, as I didn't find equivalent of `axis=1` in `pyspark`, I couldn't convert it to that. My dataset has 60 million rows and 40 columns, so the suggestion should be efficient (e.g., I cannot loop over them).

Comment: there isn't any pyspark function that can directly do that. however, you can try to look into "Pandas API on pyspark".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add all columns (except `ID`) to a new [array column](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/api/sql/index.html#array) (called `arr` below), then [sort](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/api/sql/index.html#sort_array) this array and then print out the [index](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/api/sql/index.html#array_position) of each value in the sorted array:

```python
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[1]") \
    .appName("werner").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
    
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 2, 6, 3),
                            (2, 7, 7, 4),
                            (3, 9, 4, 8),
                            (4, 10, 2, 5)],
                            ["ID", "a", "b", "c"])

cols = df.columns
cols.remove('ID')

expr = [F.col('ID')] + [F.expr(f'array_position(arr, {c})').alias(f'{c}') for c in cols]

df.withColumn('arr', F.sort_array(F.array(cols), False)) \
 .select(expr) \
 .show()
```

Result:

```
+---+---+---+---+
| ID|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  3|  1|  2|
|  2|  1|  1|  3|
|  3|  1|  3|  2|
|  4|  1|  3|  2|
+---+---+---+---+
```